# Como alinhar botões com flexbox no Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, flexbox

Estou com dificuldade para alinhar os botões em uma tela usando flexbox. Já tentei várias combinações da propriedade *fxLayoutAlign* mas não consigo o resultado esperado. O que pretendo fazer é alinhar 3 botões da seguinte forma:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Esse é o meu trecho de código atual:

```
<div fxLayout="row">
  <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <meu-botao nome="voltar" (onClique)="voltar()" label="Voltar" icone="keyboard_arrow_left" tipo="button"
      cor="primary"></meu-botao>
  </div>

  <div fxLayoutAlign="end center">
    <meu-botao nome="editar" (onClique)="editar()" *ngIf="showEditButton" label="Editar" icone="edit" tipo="button"
      cor="primary"></meu-botao>

    <meu-botao nome="excluir" (onClique)="deletar()" *ngIf="showDeleteButton" label="Excluir" icone="delete"
      tipo="button" cor="warn"></meu-botao>
  </div>
</div>
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo simples, vc tem que colocar `margin-right:auto` no seu primeiro `btn`, isso vai fazer ele "empurrar" o restante dos botões para direita do `container flex`.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

button:nth-child(1) {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>btn1</button>
    <button>btn2</button>
    <button>btn3</button>
</div>
```

---

No seu caso, como vc está usando Bootstrap vc pode dividir em duas colunas sedo que na segunda coluna vc vai usar a classe `text-right`, isso vai enviar os btns para direita.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col start center mr-auto">
            <meu-botao nome="voltar" (onclique)="voltar()" label="Voltar" icone="keyboard_arrow_left" tipo="button" cor="primary">btn1</meu-botao>
        </div>

        <div class="col end center text-right">
            <meu-botao nome="editar" (onclique)="editar()" *ngif="showEditButton" label="Editar" icone="edit" tipo="button" cor="primary">btn2</meu-botao>

            <meu-botao nome="excluir" (onclique)="deletar()" *ngif="showDeleteButton" label="Excluir" icone="delete" tipo="button" cor="warn">btn3</meu-botao>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @hugocsl. Eu estou usando o flex-alyout do Angular https://github.com/angular/flex-layout. Vou tentar a sua ideia pra ver se resolve.

Comment: @ClaudivanMoreira vc tem que ver na documentação qual é o atributo para `text-align:right`, acho que essa opção vai funcionar para vc melhor do que `margin-lft/right:auto` no botão.

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl, funfou!

Comment: @ClaudivanMoreira legal que deu certo ai, se resolveu considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas de resposta. Depois se aparecer outra resposta que te agrade mais vc pode mudar isso a hora que quiser. Vlw 